# Cannot get inner text of a span element

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the following html:

```
<tr>
    <td><span class="getme font-weight-bold">0 <img alt="user" class="user-icon" src="image1.png"></span></td>
</tr>
```

I successfully get the `tr`, then I want to the inner text of the `span` element which has the class "getme". So I do:

```
var e = row.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class, 'getme')]");
```

But it's returning `null`.

However, if I do:

```
var e = row.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class, 'font-weight-bold')]");
```

It does work fine, and I do get the inner text.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your code is working. It returns 0 as InnerText. Is that you want? `HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            var e = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class, 'getme')]").InnerText;`

Comment: @GaurangDave For me it's returning null on the `SelectSingleNode`

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Can you share what is your `row` object contains? and other code block if required.

Comment: @GaurangDave `row` is quite a big object. Editing my question.

Comment: it works fine with the following code for row: var txt = "<tr><td><span class=\"getme font-weight-bold\">0 <img alt = \"user\" class=\"user-icon\" src=\"image1.png\"></span></td></tr>";
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(txt);
            var row = doc.DocumentNode;

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono I am not doubting you but can you make sure that `row` object contains the html you mentioned in the question? I ran your code and its working properly so I am not clear about `row`.